# Backup in oracle db using triggers

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, triggers

I have 2 identical tables, just change the name table1 and table2, when 3 records are entered in table1 the information of this table must be copied to table 2 and table 1 must be empty again.

```
CREATE TABLE TABLA1(
ID_1 NUMBER PRIMARY KEY, NOMBRE VARCHAR2(40));

CREATE TABLE TABLA2(
ID_1 NUMBER PRIMARY KEY, NOMBRE VARCHAR2(40));

SELECT * FROM TABLA1;
SELECT * FROM TABLA2;


SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER DISP_BACKUP
BEFORE INSERT ON TABLA1
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
CURSOR CUR_CUENTA IS SELECT * FROM TABLA1;
--CURSOR CUR_CUENTA IS SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLA1;
var_rows := SQL%ROWCOUNT;
--CURCHOISE SQL%ROWCOUNT;
BEGIN
dbms_output.put_line('NUMERO DE REGISTROS EN TABLA 1' || CUR_CUENTA%ROWCOUNT 
);
--OPEN CUR_CUENTA;
IF CUR_CUENTA%ROWCOUNT > 3 THEN
IF INSERTING THEN
INSERT INTO TABLA2 (ID_1,NOMBRE) VALUES (:NEW.ID_1,:NEW.NOMBRE);
END IF;
DELETE FROM TABLA1;
END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: It seems you forgot to ask your question.

Comment: the code does not work, the logic inside the trigger does not work.
I try to use %rowcount to count the 3 records but I can not make it work.

Comment: You haven't fetched from the cursor so its rowcount will be zero. But it won't do what you want anyway, and if you query the table the trigger is against you'll get a mutating table error. You are also only counting existing rows, not the one that fires the triiger; and you are only copying that one (not all of them) to the other table. This seems really odd, and not something you should do in a trigger - though you could try with an after-statement trigger, perhaps.

Comment: If what way is this a backup? The records in `TABLA2` are not a backup of `TABLA1` because you go on to delete those records from `TABLA1`. A single set of records is not a backup.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to use a statement trigger instead of a row trigger - otherwise you can't access the table on which the trigger is defined. You also probably want to use an `AFTER INSERT` instead of a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER DISP_BACKUP
  AFTER INSERT ON TABLA1
DECLARE
  TYPE typRowIDCollection IS TABLE OF ROWID;

  colROWIDs   typRowIDCollection;
BEGIN
  SELECT ROWID
    BULK COLLECT INTO colROWIDs
    FROM TABLA1;

  dbms_output.put_line('NUMERO DE REGISTROS EN TABLA 1' || colROWIDs.COUNT);

  IF colROWIDs.COUNT >= 3 THEN
    FORALL i IN colROWIDs.FIRST..colROWIDs.LAST
      INSERT INTO TABLA2 (ID_1, NOMBRE)
        SELECT ID_1, NOMBRE
          FROM TABLA1
          WHERE ROWID = colROWIDs(i);

    FORALL i IN colROWIDs.FIRST..colROWIDs.LAST 
      DELETE FROM TABLA1 WHERE ROWID = colROWIDS(i);
  END IF;
END DISP_BACKUP;
```

That oughta do it.